# rbenv の一部機能 (version versions) がおかしくなった

Tags: ruby, linux, rbenv

rbenvの機能がいつからかおかしくなりました。
ruby rbenvを再インストールする事無しで修正できればと思っています。
方法がありますか？

**実行環境:**

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-77-generic x86_64)

インストールされている Ruby バージョン (2.4.1, 2.7.3, 3.0.1)

rbenv は最新バージョンだと思います。

```sh
% rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.2-61-g585ed84

% rbenv versions
rbenv: version `2.7.3' is not installed (set by /home/xxxxx/.ruby-version)
  system

% cat /home/xxxxx/.ruby-version
2.7.3

% ruby -v
ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

良く考えないでanyenv を導入した事が原因のようです。
私の軽率なミスのようです。